# how to check whether the e-mail sent successfully? (I used <a href="mailto) .can we do this using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

i am calling this function on load event of body.

```
<script>
function ...()
{
....
    var linkelement=document.getElementById("link");    
    var url = 'mailto:support@talentserv.co.in?body='+data+'&amp;subject=issue';    
    linkelement.href = url;
}
</script>
<a  id='link' style="cursor: pointer;"><u>here</u></a>
```

please try to give me answer in java script .
when i click on here the outlook gets open and when i click on send it disappears and now i want to display message of successful sending.

Comment: In a word, you cant. The process is outside of the browser.

Comment: What prevented you from formatting your question properly before hitting "submit"? Or using capital letters to begin your sentences?

Comment: @jeff that's two words :)

Comment: It is impossible. Outlook is outside browser functionality, you cannot catch outlook send, close or other events. Imagine if you have opened ms word, you simply cannot get with your browser what is going in there.

Comment: @AD7six - I didn't say I could count :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit- This is a newcomer and they may struggle with English (or it may not even be their first language), let's try to be welcoming and constructive.

Comment: thank you sir. will you tell me to redirect to a php page using url through javascript?

Comment: yes sir i am a newcommer , i will learn your ways very soon

Answer (score 2):

The `mailto` URI scheme will only open up the user's default mail program. You cannot determine if it was sent successfully using this method. If you would like to find out if mail was sent successfully you will have to user another language like PHP, it has a `mail` function with a boolean return on success/failure.

Comment: sir, will you tell me to redirect to a php page using url through javascript?

Comment: If you're going to use PHP it will be a whole different beast for you to conquer. Read up on some tutorials (it's easy to learn!) and then take a look at the [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Comment: your answer is right. but i can not vote it as 45 sec are over